# How to prevent duplication of values for a columns pair when doing a MySQL INSERT?

Tags: php, mysql

A table in my DB has the following columns: ID, campaign_id, opt_out_day
The method that inserts a set of "opt-out-days" - an array of DATETIME values - is as follows:

```
/**
 * @param  Integer $campaignId  
 * @param  Array   $optOutDays  Array of DATETIME values
 */
public function addCampaignOptOutDays($campaignId, $optOutDays) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `".self::$tblOptOutDays."`
                  (campaign_id, opt_out_day)
                  VALUES
                  (:campaign_id, :opt_out_day)";

        try {
            $this->connection->beginTransaction();
            $query = $this->connection->prepare($query);
            $query->bindParam(':campaign_id', $campaignId, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
            foreach ($optOutDays as $day) {
                $query->bindParam(':opt_out_day', $day, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->execute();
            }
            $this->connection->commit();
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            $this->connection->rollback();
            throw new \Models\Database\DatabaseException($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

How can I modify the query in order to prevent duplicating the same opt-out-day for a campaign? In other words, multiple rows with the same opt-out-day can exist in this table, as long as they have different a 'campaign-id'. 
Adding a unique key for the (campaign_id, opt_out_day) is not an option though, as I don't want to throw exceptions when such situations occur, I just want to not add the pair again.

Comment: You can use `INSERT IGNORE` so the MySQL won't throw an error when it meets a duplicate. You should have unique index in there because no matter what the wrong values will slip by one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

This will avoid an extra SELECT query but will also avoid an error if you have duplicate keys.

There's also INSERT IGNORE ... but that might ignore other errors as well

Comment: You'll want to check the affected rows value if you use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. It will be 1 for an insert, or 2 for an update. In the `ON UPDATE` part, set the column values to the same values, and the update will be skipped.

Comment: Thanks Markus I've updated the answer to reflect part of the more detailed expanation you gave.

Comment: @KayNelson, Haha. This is true, the OP will still need the unique index.

Answer (score 0):

As Jakub Kania commented, you could use a unique index and use [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

> With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error occurs.
>   Ignored errors may generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key
>   errors do not.

Then, simply check the affected rows value to see if the insert was successful.

So, other errors can still be detected, as warnings. I think `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is a better solution, given you add the unique index because checking warnings can be a pain.

Comment: "Adding a unique key for the (campaign_id, opt_out_day) is not an option though, as I don't want to throw exceptions when such situations occur, I just want to not add the pair again."

Comment: @KayNelson, `INSERT IGNORE` doesn't throw exceptions.

Comment: No, but you need a unique index in order to run INSERT IGNORE. Otherwise it simply just inserts it and you get duplicates.

Comment: @KayNelson, agreed that you need a unique index for this solution and I mentioned that in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Im not familiair with php, but what if you select from the table and check if that returns a value, if not then insert?

Try

```
$checkquery = "SELECT 1 FROM `".self::$tblOptOutDays."` 
WHERE campaign_id=:campaign_id AND opt_out_day=:opt_out_day)";
```

Then

```
IF $checkquery <> 1 THEN
// run insert
```

Comment: This will have concurrency issues, meaning you could get duplicates.

Comment: No it wont? It checks if that combination value exists `(campign_id AND opt_out_date)` that you want to insert, if it doenst the checkquery will return empty meaning the if check would be true and insert would occur.

Comment: If two people run the SELECT query at the same time, both SELECTs will return no result, and both sessions may insert the same value. If you can think of a scenario will the above will work, please explain. I wasn't the one who down-voted, by the way.